# Using flamingo ribbon in e4 application

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4, radiance-flamingo

I just started an application using flaming ribbon technology (http://insubstantial.github.io/insubstantial/flamingo/) and it looks nice. Because the software package is growing very fast, I want to use a more flexible way to handle code and application. Looking around, I found that the e4 (eclipse rich client platform) would fit my needs. I like this plug-in technology and now I am wondering, if there is any way to integrate the flamingo ribbon technolgy into e4 applications. 
I am not bounded to the eclipse rcp, but I need a plugin-framework, moveable and dockable windows and the flamingo ribbon bar. Does anyone have a recommendation or hints how to integrate flamingo into e4?
Cheers Carsten

Comment: Flamingo appears to be Swing, e4 is SWT or JavaFX. You can use Swing with SWT but it is best avoided.

Comment: greg-449, you are right. Flamingo is a Swing based framework, but I think in e4 it is possible to use/create a custom renderer for use with Swing. But up to now, I didn't found out how to create and how to use such renderer.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Renderer/article.html describes e4 renderers, they are not easy to use.